# Force pre-computation of a constant

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation, compile-time, template-haskell

I have a constant declaration in Haskell -- can I force this to be evaluated ahead of time? I'm seeing some code that looks roughly like,

```
myList = [(a, b), (c, d)]
...
map (f . fst) myList
```

take time in the `fst` call when I profile it (it does have 168M calls). The binary representation of `myList` is quite small, and could be, for example, copied into global memory [if this were a C program]. I'm compiling with `-O3 -optc-O3` of course.

Thanks very much!

#### Generating Lift instances for a custom type

Any expression given to the `lift` call in sclv's answer must be an instance of Lift. There's a library named `th-lift` which will generate Lift instances for custom data types. See that package's [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/th-lift/0.5.3/doc/html/Language-Haskell-TH-Lift.html).

Comment: I notice that when I write something like "!myList = ..." it will say "Top-level bang-pattern bindings aren't allowed" ... maybe this is forbidden by design?

Comment: You can (probably) do this using Template Haskell. It will be inconvenient. Hopefully there is an easier way.

Comment: A top level bang pattern, if it worked, would only force the top level cons of the list.

Comment: Is it the expression `map (f . fst) myList` which you want evaluated at compile time?

Comment: @augustss: if a top-level bang pattern did work, then you could use a deepSeq to ensure that it really did force the entire list.

Comment: @Ganesh Absolutely.  Given that this seems to be a common request, perhaps it should be turned into a ghc feature request.  Of course, having the compiler perform arbitrary computations could take a long time.

Comment: You'd also have to decide whether to evaluate top-level bang patterns at compile-time, or eagerly at application startup. I'd favour the latter, with a pragma for the former.

Comment: Would you be happy to speculatively evaluate it ahead of time using `par` ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generating a compile-time constant using Template Haskell:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Language.Haskell.TH.Syntax(Lift(..))

test = $(lift $ (map (*20) [0..100] :: [Int]))
```

`lift` takes a Haskell value and lifts it into a TH Exp. The `$()` runs the enclosed quote, and splices the generated exp into the code at compile time.

Comment: Thanks very much, this looks right. I'll have to learn some more tempalte haskell before I can verify it works on my real-world example, but this sounds like the right approach. (I'm currently getting this "GHC stage restriction: ... is used in a top-level splice or annotation, and must be imported, not defined locally" message.)

Comment: @gatoatigrado: Right. Any of the values you use inside the splice have to be defined in another module. After all, they're run before the module is fully compiled :-)

Comment: Okay, I got it to work... unfortunately, it doesn't help the performance scene though. I think Don's comment was hinting that the expense of computing the constant was all that mattered, not that its access would become faster when compiled.